# не получается скомпилировать код

Tags: c++

Не могу скомпилировать код на маке в терминале. Ввожу команду `clang++ main.cpp -o main`, но в ответ терминал выдает ошибку:

```
ld: Undefined symbols

  _main, referenced from:

      <initial-undefines>

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Пытался загуглить все это дело, но везде такая проблема у людей с кодом где уже куча разных функций. В общем сложно это все.
Версия clang 15

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double gallons, liters;
    cout << "Введите количество галлонов: ";
        cin >> gallons; // Ввод данных от пользователя
        liters = gallons * 3.7854; // Преобразование в литры
        cout << "Литров: " << liters;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может лучше для начала код main.cpp привести в качестве исходника? Мало ли что Вы там написали.

Comment: Линкер не может найти `main()`. Либо в объявлении функции ошибка, либо модуль с этой функцией не добавлен в проект.

Comment: @Ingvar, код добавил, подскажите пожалуйста что не так

Comment: @LShadow77, код добавил, что может быть не так?

Comment: `int main(int argc, char** argv) {... `

Comment: [проблема не воспроизводится](https://godbolt.org/z/sd7xWvT4G)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, не помогло. По прежнему та же ошибка

Comment: Наверное что-то из clang библиотек  у вас недоустановлено

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путь к файлу был судя по всему не правильный. При вводе в терминал команды cat main.cpp ничего не происходило, терминал просто ждал следующей команды. На деле в VSCode был открыт один путь, который был в следствие перемешения файла в родительскую папку, не верным, а в терминале верным.